# Storing binary data to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Haven't used Node for quite some time and got stuck on what should be a fairly easy task.

I want to receive binary data (in this case an image) and just pass it on to a MongoDB document without the extra steps of storing the file on the filesystem, saving it to DB and then delete it from the filesystem. Ideally without using any github home-brews or other fifth-party libs.
In the output I get additional data from the multipart (------WebKitFormBoundary etc) which is kinda ruining the party.

Any ideas?

```
// ... server code
app.use(bodyParser.raw({ type: 'multipart/form-data'}));
// ... more server code

router.route('/image/upload')
    .post(function (req, res) {
        console.log(req.body);
    });
```

The log shows the data as hex:

```
<Buffer 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 57 65 62 4b 69 74 46 6f 72 6d 42 6f 75 6e 64 61 72 79 64 48 49 43 43 67 30 65 32 6f 41 52 75 35 52 49 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d ... >
```

...and this is what it contains:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarydHICCg0e2oARu5RI
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="filename.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

image data <-- The stuff I'm interested in storing

------WebKitFormBoundarydHICCg0e2oARu5RI--
```